# How to use Google Speech API from Codename One?

Tags: speech-recognition, codenameone, google-speech-api

I want to record audio from the phone, and then send it to the google speech non-streaming API. I can record using Capture.captureAudio(), but then I do not know what is the audio encoding and the sample rate, since they are needed [for the api request](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1beta1/RecognitionConfig).
How can I get the audio encoding and the sample rate, so that I can send them with my API request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [sources](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/Android/src/com/codename1/impl/android/AndroidImplementation.java#L5577) on Android it records in AMR-WB

```
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(temp.getAbsolutePath());
```

Google speech API accepts AMR-WB if you properly [set audio format](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1beta1/RecognitionConfig#audioencoding).

Another problem is that file is recorded as AMR-WB in 3GPP container, so you need a custom code to extract audio data form 3GPP, you can find it [here](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=181):

```
// #!AMR\n
private static byte[] AMR_MAGIC_HEADER = {0x23, 0x21, 0x41, 0x4d, 0x52, 0x0a};


public byte[] convert3gpDataToAmr(byte[] data) {
    if (data == null) {
        return null;
    }

    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    // read FileTypeHeader
    FileTypeBox ftypHeader = new FileTypeBox(bis);
    // You can check if it is correct here
    // read MediaDataHeader
    MediaDataBox mdatHeader = new MediaDataBox(bis);
    // You can check if it is correct here
    int rawAmrDataLength = mdatHeader.getDataLength();
    int fullAmrDataLength = AMR_MAGIC_HEADER.length + rawAmrDataLength;
    byte[] amrData = new byte[fullAmrDataLength];
    System.arraycopy(AMR_MAGIC_HEADER, 0, amrData, 0, AMR_MAGIC_HEADER.length);
    bis.read(amrData, AMR_MAGIC_HEADER.length, rawAmrDataLength);
    return amrData;
}
```

Also note that AMR-WB gives you slightly lower accuracy, so you might want to consider raw audio capture with more detailed API, not codenameone.

Comment: What about platforms other than Android? Do I have to use native interfaces for every platform?

Comment: iOS and BlackBerry also record amr. I'm not sure what other platforms are you interested in

Comment: You can capture AMR which will work on iOS, Android and possibly other OS's using the Codename One API: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/media/MediaManager.html#createMediaRecorder-java.lang.String-java.lang.String- You can get the OS supported mimetypes thru https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/media/MediaManager.html#getAvailableRecordingMimeTypes--

Comment: Shai, would you write a simple example of calling the API without hardcoding AMR? I am not able to open the input stream after MediaManager.createMediaRecorder(filename, "audio/amr");
I am trying: Storage.getInstance().createInputStream(filename);

Comment: See this: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/iOSPort/src/com/codename1/impl/ios/IOSImplementation.java#L2751-L2777